# Choice of articles: the reduction/ a reduction /reduction

Tags: nouns, articles

I am often confused about the use of articles before abstract nouns. Are the following three sentences all grammatically correct? If so, what differences are there, if any, in their meaning or nuance?

(1) Obama chose the middle ground, ordering the reduction of U.S. troops to 50,000 by August 2010.

(2) Obama chose the middle ground, ordering a reduction of U.S. troops to 50,000 by August 2010.

(3) Obama chose the middle ground, ordering reduction of U.S. troops to 50,000 by August 2010.

Please assume that this reduction of troops has not been mentioned before this sentence, thus "the reduction" in (1) does not refer to something already mentioned.

Comment: Great question. I'm a native speaker, and I can tell you that (1) and (2) are both fine, and mean the same thing, but (3) doesn't sound right. However, I have no idea why.

Comment: Thank you, Peter. "(3) doesn't sound right" is apparently the sense we non-native speakers don't have.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer this because I think both answers are partially wrong.

The sticking point is example 3, which omits the article.

I submit that this is *not* wrong (and certainly not "just plain wrong"). The omission of an article there is an example of *ellipsis*:

> **ellipsis** *noun*
> the omission from speech or writing of a word or words that are superfluous or able to be understood from contextual clues.
> [NOAD]

There are many examples of articles being omitted without confusion.

> The president ordered cessation of hostilities.
>
> The Selective Service System mandated registration of all draft-eligible citizens by 2014.

In these examples an article could be used ("a cessation", "the registration") but is simply not required.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Robusto. This explains much! I occasionally see or hear sentences using "zero article plus a singular abstract noun" where the use of "a" or "the" seems appropriate and have become really confused. Your answer is a great help!

Comment: In your "cessation" and "registration" examples, the omission sounds fine, and I agree that it is probably best characterised as ellipsis. The question is, in which situations is this ellipsis acceptable? Ellipsis like this evokes head-line language, or a cursory style. If the sentence contains elements that are the opposite of such a style, ellipsis is either judged incongruous or not recognised as such. In the original "reduction" example, there may be some elements that seem to clash with the required cursory style; I, for one, find the ellipsis less palatable there than in your examples.

Comment: @Cerberus: Like anything else in language, you have to know when to use it and when not to.

Comment: @Robusto: And in most cases we know when, but not why.

Comment: @Cerberus: There are two examples of the usage of "lack of" in Macmillan Dictionary (online): "The game was canceled because of lack of interest." and "Most of his problems stem from a lack of confidence."  Is the first one explained as a case of ellipsis in your view? And if so, is it an ellipsis of "a" or "the"?

Comment: @Fairdinkum: That would be ellipsis of *a*. However, *lack* is probably a special case, in that it can be a part of various idiomatic constructions, which makes it more difficult to analyse. Consider, for example, how *for lack of* is much more common than either *for a lack of* or *because of (a) lack of*, all with the same meaning. It is possible that *lack of* without an article began as ellipsis but later became idiomatic, but it is hard to differentiate factors.

Comment: @Cerberus: Thank you so much. Please bear with me for one more shot. Regarding your comment, "That would be ellipsis of _a_", why isn't there _the_ in front of ellipsis? I understand that there cannot be _a_ in front of _ellipsis_, which is, unlike _reduction_ or _lack_, always uncountable. But can't you say that this _ellipsis_ is somewhat defined by _of a_, justifying the use of _the_ in front of it?

Comment: Sorry but I disagree that 3) is a case for ellipsis. It is impossible to tell without more context, but by itself, 3) requires an article and sounds extremely choppy and awkward without one (ie. caveman speak).

Answer (score 0):

(2) is most correct. (1) is okay but a little awkward.

To me, the president talking about a reduction that will happen in the future seems unspecific enough to warrant the indefinite article '*a/an*' If we were talking about a troop decrease that had already occurred, then the definite article '*the*' would be more applicable:

"The reduction in troops that Obama ordered finally ended the war."

(3) is just plain wrong because it omits the article altogether.

This sentence could be cleaned up even more by tweaking (2) to be:

Obama chose the middle ground, ordering a reduction in U.S. troops to 50,000 by August 2010.

Comment: Can you explain why 3rd is wrong? It sounds right to me and I am obviously wrong

Comment: Thank you, mattacular. Do you have any idea why (3) is wrong? I just found the following sentence, which further confuses me. "Climate change mitigation, through reduction of greenhouse gas concentrations, is the primary aim for governments and communities."

Comment: Because it is missing an article before the noun 'reduction.' Same reason this sentence would be wrong: I want sandwich. Add the article and it is golden: I want a sandwich. So the meat of this question is: 'which article is right for modifying "reduction" in this sentence?' English only has 2 articles - the and a/an - but you need to use one of them!

Comment: I added some more to my original answer for clarity!

Comment: "Correct" is really very much like "pregnant": it really isn't gradable except when you say "almost correct" or "mostly correct". If it doesn't get full marks, then it's less than correct. If my 18th birthday is tomorrow, then today I'm still legally a minor and not an adult, a "pre-man" and not a "man" (just a "male child").

Comment: Do both "through the reduction of greenhouse gas concentrations" and "through a reduction in greenhouse gas concentrations" in this case get full marks in your view then?

Comment: Those sound right to me.

Answer (score 0):

Sentence one is perfectly grammatical and idiomatic American English.

Sentence 2 sounds a bit better to me stated as "...ordering a reduction **in** U.S. troops to 50,000...", but I don't see anything "wrong" with it. My stylistic bias may be idiosyncratic, but I wouldn't bother editing that sentence for a newspaper article.

Sentence 3 requires either "**a** reduction" or "**the** reduction": singular abstract nouns usually require articles or other determiners, and this one is no exception. I would edit in an article here.

Comment: Thank you, Bill.  So do you think the following sentence is incorrect?    "Climate change mitigation, through reduction of greenhouse gas concentrations, is the primary aim for governments and communities."